# Linq average for each employee

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, linq

I want to get average bids amounts in auction for each user with linq, here's my tables.

Employee

```
int ID
varchar Name
varchar Surname
```

Bids

```
int ID
int UserId
decimal Amount
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Have you try anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide more details we can help you develop a more specific solution. But this is roughly what you need to do:

```
var query = from e in context.Employees
            join b in context.Bids on e.ID equals b.UserId
            group new { e, b } by e.ID into g
            select new
            { 
              Employee = g.FirstOrDefault().e,
              AverageBid = g.Average(x => x.b.Amount),
            };
```